How do I get an appsheet calendar reference to read dates in 2025?
I have the following appsheet reference between a list of events and a calendar.
SELECT(Calendar[Var],CONTAINS([Location],[_THISROW].[Key]))
This grabs all the data up to Dec. 31 2024 but stops at 1/1/2025 despite the data existing. Is there something wrong with this reference?
I recreated the app with different data and a different calendar and hit the same issue. I am expecting the reference to work for all dates, including 2024.

I got this working. I had to change this setting  {“FromDaysInThePast”:-90,“ToDaysInTheFuture”:90} in table settings to adjust the time frame.
